# Can we integrate Mathematica with Unreal Engine (Version 4.25) ,to access the scenarios and create SLAM in mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, unreal-engine4

I want to connect Mathematica with Unreal Engine to export the scenarios in unreal engine to conduct SLAM ( Simultaneous Localization and Mapping).

Comment: Sure you can - both Mathematica and Unreal have polished SDKs.

Comment: There are resources available to show how to integrate Mathematica and Unity, I imagine they might provide some information useful to you.  And as @Dai has already pointed out, both softwares have SDKs for integration. Point your favourite search engine in those directions.